# Why MySQL error using table alias on a simple select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using phpmyadmin to test out some MySQL queries. I'm trying to write a larger, nested query, which is failing due to an unrecognized table alias, so I'm trying to debug smaller parts of it. However, I'm getting confusing errors when I try to use table aliases sometimes.

Can you explain why some of these queries throw errors?

`SELECT * FROM table1 AS tablealias1` (works)

`SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY userid` (works)

`SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY userid AS tablealias1` (error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS tablealias1
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 )

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1` (works)

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1 AS tablealias1` (same error as above)

`(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1) AS tablealias1` (same error as above)

Comment: You can't assign aliases to where or group by clauses. That's pretty basic.

Comment: `as` statements define column and table aliases.  It is allowed only in the `select` clause (for a column alias) and the `from` clause (for a table alias).  That is how SQL syntax works.

Comment: when you evaluate `WHERE userid = 1 AS tablealias1` - WHAT do you expect to be saved in `tablealias1` ? true? false?

Comment: Try this: `Select * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1) AS tablealias1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You alias things to:

- rename the column display's name
- give it a reference name for later use elsewhere in the query statement (whether you use it explicitly or implicitly--as long as it could be used elsehere)

If you're not doing either, an alias makes no sense.  You can't alias a result set unless it's used inside a subquery, then you need an alias to reference it.

This will work:

```
 Select * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1) AS tablealias1
```

as it implies

```
  Select tablealias1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1) AS tablealias1
```

Alone, this is garbage:

```
  (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE userid=1) AS tablealias1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize you couldn't give an alias to the result set ONLY unless it's inside a subquery. Even though making an alias for the result set of a single SELECT statement doesn't make practical sense, I didn't think it was invalid syntax. I was just doing these to try to debug a larger, nested query.